# Elmah not logging 404 on IIS. Logs when running on visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah, elmah.mvc

I have installed Elmah.MVC using nuget package.

When running elmah using visual studio, whenever i try to generate a 404 an error is logged to elmah. Which is the required result in my use case.

However when I run the same site on IIS no such error is logged to elmah. Why so ?

What changes do I have to do to so that all 404 are also logged to elmah.

Also : Came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698562/elmah-and-404s-under-iis6) on SO, but could not make out what extension to make.

Edit: here is what I am trying to generate 404 - `someurl/generate404`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to log 404 for static file, and the reason it can not log it because it did not go through asp.net hence elmah can not log it.

I personally have not tried it, but See if this SO [Elmah not logging 404 (missing files / images)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892233/elmah-not-logging-404-missing-files-images) mentioning changing mode work.

I think the thread answer you mentioned is referring to this:
http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-integrated-pipeline

Comment: No I am not trying to log 404 fr static file.